# Using Eclipse with Arabic and English on the same line

Tags: eclipse, arabic

I just noticed as I was doing a string compare in Eclipse that when I place an Arabic character in a line it completely throws off Eclipse.  How can I interchange English and Arabic on a single line of code?

** EDIT **

Ok now that my question has been migrated here, I supposed some code is in order.  I was trying to do the following in Java:

```
Character c1 = 'ة';
Map<Character, Double> arabicRootMap = new HashMap<Character, Double>();
arabicRootMap.put(c1, 5.0);
```

The exact same thing happens here on SO as in Eclipse where instead of putting c1 into my map, I would like to put my Arabic character into the map directly, but my left to right is order is partly broken and the new mixed cursor navigation on the line is crazy.  As you see, I have an indirect solution to the problem by defining a character beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that is my answer, substitution whenever you have a character or string which needs to be in the middle of a statement.  This gets to be rather labor intesive as you build up strings of various lengths and can not pre-define every Arabic word ever written.  If there is a better answer, I would like to hear it.